# How do you type a response from an API call in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function in TypeScript that fetches data from an API and returns it, but I keep getting an error on the response object that is returned from the API call.

```
interface IAppointments {
    results: []
}

export function getAppointments(): Promise<IAppointments> {
    return fetch('https://dewey-smart.herokuapp.com/appointments', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers : {
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
      })    
      .then(data => data.json()) // error: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type
}
```

I tried playing around with it, but I can't seem to figure out a type for `data` that doesn't give an error. I also tried adjusting the code to add `.then(res => {return res as IAppointments})` at the end of the method, but this didn't work either.

Any solutions?

Comment: No great way, unfortunately - using `as` to assert the return type is the only way to go nowadays, I think. The `fetch(...).then(data => data.json())` part should work fine at typing the `data` as a Response though https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYUwLgxgFgFA5FMYAOBnAXAekwExAdxAE8BaVAWwEMAnMAOihGoHsBrAV0uWTomfMxdkzAJYA7MORATUcADQACAN4AoBeo3qpYKMxzoFcAOIBRACry1mjeT0gDcPtVlyr1hY0p5nCg6veacADCzBLSYCRmRMggcOhwQgA2IhCUYCKhmABWqKFwbtYAvgXqhQCUmiUKdDrSMDhplAoAvAB8Cg1glHQ5oTBlZQDcQA

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAOmD2owC2E4AzsgN4BQyNyUEJArgDZgkBcyA2gLqUC+lShAAeuKGGQxGIBGGA4QyAOYQwWXPiKkAFAEpOABSg4CwEhAA8GbHnDa2APgrVa9MIyhKYahAAsdAHI-MDBMDgB6CIATCAB3CABPAFoSAjgJADo-aBwAa0Y4bEyEUwiizXtiNkCAGhdaRuQiMD8caM5AgHEAUQAVOtcm5vaITtKoEkHhmhy4WMnkTioZ2kCAYUVIcGS+xMwIQPZAiuZgBDh5RQiAKxJFQKGmwWH+PUanmkzW4h1oy7gyAAvM5-mA4Jk7op9O8oshoCYoEYMnAWtBkIEwXBAshgARMGcEMAwMxEsg-HAyHAlCcQIkcWB9hABEA) the `noImplicitAny` option in the TS config is enabled.